# Detect monomer from from multimer structure in PDB files?

Tags: protein-structure, pdb, data-preprocessing

I have a bunch of .pdb files that consist of protein-peptide structures. However, before start working with them I need to clean them. Now, I can easily remove water, ion, or other stuff like BMET, BASN, BARG info, and anisotropic temperature information. Now, if the PDB flies consist of more than one instance of protein-peptide then it will be hard for me to work with them. The chains of protein and peptide numbers are arbitrary. For example, in a PDB file, a protein may have 4 chains(A, B, C, D) of proteins and 4 peptide chains(E, F, G, H). In that case, it may have 4 instances and we can select A and E to get a single instance from it. But, in pdb file, protein may have 4 chains(A,B,C,D) of proteins and 2 peptide chains(E,F). In that case, it may have 2 instances.

**Now the question is, how to select one instance of protein-peptide from the PDB files without doing manual curation?**

Comment: set a cutoff lenght for peptide, everything smaller thn lenght X  would be a peptide.  Then to get the protein-peptide pairs , I guess you'll have to calculate wich protein chain is the peptide closest one  and assign all of the peptide to a single protein chain. Does it sound reasonable ?? No idea how to accomplish all of that though